# NextJS fast refresh performing full reload and throwing Error: failed to load script: /_next/static/chunks/pages/register.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, next.js

I'm trying to navigate via `<Link href="/register">Register</Link>` to my registration page, but when I click it I get an error/warning either saying that:

- NextJS failed to load my script:
  [image]

OR

- fast reload had to perform a full reload
  [image]

In both cases I get the same message in my terminal:
[image]

This is my register page component:

```js
import type { NextPage } from "next/types";
import type { FormEvent } from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { createUser } from "../../helpers/helperFuncs";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

const Register: NextPage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const emailInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const passwordInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  const submitHandler = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current?.value ?? "";
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current?.value ?? "";

    // create a new user
    try {
      const createdUser = await createUser(enteredEmail, enteredPassword);
      console.log("createdUser", createdUser);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.auth}>
      <h1>{"Sign Up"}</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className={styles.control}>
          <label htmlFor="email">Your Email</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" required ref={emailInputRef} />
        </div>

        <div className={styles.control}>
          <label htmlFor="password">Your Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            required
            ref={passwordInputRef}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.actions}>
          <button>{"Create Account"}</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

My createUser function that I'm importing:

```js
async function createUser(email: string, password: string) {
  const response = await fetch("/api/auth/register", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  const data = await response.json();
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(data.message || "Something went wrong");
  }
  return data;
}

export { createUser };
```

I don't understand why NextJS would be forcing full reloads, since I'm not using class components, and I don't think I'm editing anything outside of the React rendering tree.

The failed to load script error message is also beyond me, but I reckon it's got to do with webpack being weird, since it's asking for a .js file and that's also what the terminal message seems to imply. I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit1:** I've figured out that it's the usage of `className={styles.<whatever>}` that's causing these errors and forced reloads. The questions still remains though - how can I use my styles.module.scss in the correct way then?

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem similar to this. Try deleting nextjs cached files.

Delete the .next folder in your project location and restart your app.

Comment: Renaming the subfolder ".nextjs/cache" did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

1- Delete .next folder

2- Clear the cache

3- Launch project again

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because in my styles.module.scss I'm importing an image in one of my button style definitions (wanted to make the button "fully transparent" and show the root parent background on hover):

```css
  .actions button:hover {
    background-color: teal;
    border: 2px solid cyan;
    background-image: url('../../../public/images/hero-background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your component name starting with Capital Letter and also can check your css property value, such as if you use justify-content:start; then it will occer the fast refreash failure, "start" vaule is not supported by all the browser you have to use 'justify-content:flex-start'; these are the two reason not to work hot releading for that i faced the issue so far, and share it if someone can be benifited,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also tackled here:
[Next.JS 13 using appdir -> Page keeps refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883914/next-js-13-using-appdir-page-keeps-refreshing/77893260#77893260)

Just run:
npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest~

- All the best!