# how to configure and persist redux toolkit in nextjs 13

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist, next.js13

I'm having trouble using the reduxjs toolkit to persist redux with nextjs 13. The code I'm using below fails to build sync storage, according to the nextjs console. reverting to noop storage. Can anyone help to me how to use the nextjs and reduxjs toolkit to persist a redux?

Here is the actual console message error: redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage

Here is what I've done:

I have this in my store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authenticateSlice from "./slices/authenticateSlice";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { encryptTransform } from "redux-persist-transform-encrypt";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  auth: authenticateSlice.reducer,
});

let transforms = null;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  const encrypt = encryptTransform({
    secretKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REDUX_SECRET,
    onError: function (error) {
      // Handle the error.
    },
  });
  transforms = [encrypt];
}

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  transforms,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export default store;
```

then I wrapped it in my `_app.js` since I am with nextjs 13:

```
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import Head from "next/head";
import Template from "template/index";
import React from "react";
import store from "next-redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import LinearProgress from "@mui/material/LinearProgress";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

let persistor = persistStore(store);

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={<LinearProgress />}>
          <Template>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Template>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default React.memo(App);
```

Comment: which version of `redux-persist` are you using ?

Comment: "redux": "^4.2.1",
"redux-persist": "^6.x.x",
"redux-persist-transform-encrypt": "^4.0.0",
"@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.2.5",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `v6` of `redux-persist` you need to do the following:

First add the `AsyncStorage` package as follows:

```
yarn add @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

then,

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const persistConfig = {
  //...
  storage: AsyncStorage,
}
```

Please don't forget to remove the below line

```
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
```

Reference link - [Release notes for Redux-Persist v6](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/releases/tag/v6.0.0)

**UPDATE**

I guess the error you are facing is because you cannot create the local storage in `Node.js`. Hence you will need to import

```
import createWebStorage from "redux-persist/lib/storage/createWebStorage";
```

and add a check as follows:

```
const storage = typeof window !== "undefined" ? createWebStorage("local") : createNoopStorage();
```

[Here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15687#discussioncomment-45319) you will find the detailed explanation.

Comment: Error storing data ReferenceError: window is not defined

warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload.

Comment: do you get this error after making above changes ?

Comment: yes I tried the above code.

Comment: Try deleting the `.next` directory and try the `yarn` command again.

Comment: I deleted .next folder and yarn dev. I got this
Error storing data ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: This is a bit strange. Are you try to access `window` object anywhere in your code? Please check these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74639543/nextjs-fast-refresh-performing-full-reload-and-throwing-error-failed-to-load-sc and https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40184

Comment: event - compiled client and server successfully in 266 ms (1214 modules)
redux-persist failed to create sync storage. falling back to noop storage.
Error storing data ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: if anyone found any answer, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering an error related to "window" being undefined, this is because Next.js supports server-side rendering (SSR) out of the box. This means that the initial page is rendered on the server.

With Redux, there's an issue:
The server will render the page using the initial state of your Redux store, and then send this to the client. The client will then "hydrate" (or replace the server-rendered content) using the client-side JavaScript.

The issue is ensuring that the Redux state that was used for server-side rendering matches the initial state on the client side, to prevent mismatches or re-rendering.

Use `next-redux-wrapper` to create the store only on the client side and hydrate on the server side.

Then add to your store:

```
import { HYDRATE, createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
```

Don't remove your original store code, just place this under your original store code.

```
  const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState = {
      ...state, 
      ...action.payload
    }
    return nextState
  } else {
    return persistedReducer(state, action)
  }
}

const initStore = () => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: reducer,
  });
}

export const wrapper = createWrapper(initStore);
```

Then in your _app.js add:

```
import { store, wrapper } from '../app/store';
```

and finally export your "App" with:

```
export default wrapper.withRedux(App);
```

This is what helped me to get it working. I hope it helps some of you who have had "ReferenceError: window is not defined" issues